# Is there any way to know the memory address differernce between %esp and %ebp?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

(32bit assembly, so I can't use the register like r14)

Is there any way to know the memory address differernce between %esp and %ebp?

For example, if there is a less then two element in the stack, I want to go back to the read_token, which goes back and waits for another letter.

So if the difference is less then two blocks(8), then I want to go back to read_token.

But I found out that code like below:

```
cmpl $4, (%ebp)-(%esp)
jle read_token
```

is actually impossible.

I know that

"pop one elemet/check if stack top is empty/if empty, put it back/if nonempty, goto read_token "

is possible, but I think it is so complicated and might have more simpler way... can anyone help me?

Comment: I also tried counting the number of stacks using %ecx, but I somehow got into corruption so I am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: Are `(%ebp)` and `(%esp)` in your expression supposed to be memory operands, or are you actually trying to check register values?  You'll want a tmp register, for example `lea -4(%ebp), %eax` / `cmp %eax, %esp` / `jbe stack_pointer_is_right_below_ebp`.  (Use unsigned compares for addresses; your stack could span the signed-overflow boundary.)

Comment: I am trying to check the adress values!

Comment: Then don't write `(%reg)` - that means memory operand in AT&T syntax.  Anyway, LEA / CMP in last comment is what you're looking for, right?  To implement `if(esp <= ebp-4)`.  (I think I named the branch target wrong for that condition: I wasn't thinking about how AT&T syntax makes branch condition names backwards.)

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you so much for helping! I want to give you a million upvotes

Answer (score 2):

To implement `do { } while(esp <= ebp -4);` you'll want a tmp register, for example

```
.loop:                          # do{
   ...

   lea -4(%ebp), %eax                  # eax = ebp-4
   cmp %eax, %esp                      # AT&T means compare mnemonics are backwards
   jbe .Lloop                   # }while(esp <= ebp-4)
```

Use unsigned compares for addresses; your stack could span the signed-overflow boundary.

---

To actually compute the distance between two registers, simply subtract `tmp = ebp-esp`:

```
   mov   %ebp, %eax
   sub   %esp, %eax

  # cmp   $4, %eax
  # j??  somewhere
```

But obviously this is less efficient if you just want to branch on the result, costing an extra `mov` instruction vs. the LEA version where we could copy-and-add a negative constant all in one instruction.